# JavaScript: Arrays in function parmater list

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parameters

I have come across a construction similar this:

```js
function test([a,b],c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}

test([3,5,7],'hello');  //  => 3,5,hello
```

What is does is easy enough to follow, and it works well enough in the browsers I have tested, but I didn’t know that you could use an actual array in the function parameter list.

What is the array in the parameter list called, and where is this explained (preferably in MDN)? Is this a newish feature?

Answer (score 0):

It is called **destructuring**. From the MDN article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.
>
> **Description**
> The object and array literal expressions provide an easy way to create ad hoc packages of data.
>
> ```
> const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> ```
>
> The destructuring assignment uses similar syntax, but on the left-hand side of the assignment to define what values to unpack from the sourced variable.
>
> ```
> const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> const [y, z] = x;
> console.log(y); // 1
> console.log(z); // 2
> ```

Comment: I am aware of destructuring assignments, but the linked article doesn’t mention it in terms of function parameters. There is a section mentioning unpacking fields from objects, so maybe that’s the idea?

Comment: @Manngo: It works the same way with function parameters.